# JavaScript Sequential / Synchronous Callback Functions Inside For Loop

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I currently have this situation...

```
function loop (num1, callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        console.log("loop count: " + i);
        callback();
    }
}
```

Which is currently outputting the following sample results:

```
loop count: 1
loop count: 2
loop count: 3
...
loop count: num1 - 1
callback output 1
callback output 2
callback output 3
...
callback output num1 - 1
```

What I would like it to do is wait until each callback has finished executing and outputting its result before moving onto the next item in the loop. i.e. as per the sample output below:

```
loop count: 1
callback output 1
loop count: 2
callback output 2
loop count: 3
callback output 3
...
loop count: num1 - 1
callback output num1 - 1
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this sequential / synchronous mode of operation in my function?

Thanks in advance for the help!

UPDATE...

Ok so the call back function is being called like so...

```
loop(10, updateDB);
```

And the callback function passed to loop is as follows...

```
function updateDB(sql_string, responseObject) {
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host : 'localhost',
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'database',
  });
  connection.connect();
  var query = sql_string;
  connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
      connection.end();
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        responseObject.push({"queryStatus":"FAIL"});
      }
      if (err == null) {
        console.log('Changed ' + results.changedRows + ' rows');
        responseObject.push({"queryStatus":"PASS"});
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: Is the callback function asynchronous?

Comment: Where does `callback output i` come from?

Comment: You can't achieve that with a `for` loop. You cannot pause it to manually call `next()` as you can in other languages. Besides, depending on the value of `num`, using callback could end up in an error after reaching the maximum nesting depth

Comment: Please show how you're calling `loop`.

Comment: [This does work](http://jsbin.com/moromeline/edit?js,console). Your problem is inside `callback`. Its obviously synchronous.

Comment: @Lux - if it were synchronous then wouldn't the output be as "expected"? I think you meant that callback is **a**synchrnonous

Comment: @bergi Please see updated code with passed callback function

Comment: @4castle please see updated answer with function call

Comment: @Josh Where's the promise in that code? Also, I don't think you actually want to open 10 connections.

Comment: @Bergi I am quite new to the JavaScript programming language and still learning all of the ins and outs. I'll look into these promises. Can you maybe explain how I would go about incorporating a promise into the above code to make it operate as I am intending in the question?

Comment: @Bergi as for the 10 connections good point, this is something I am intending to correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your callback is obviously asynchronous, but that doesn't void your desire to force it to execute in its entirety before moving on in your loop. Here's a way by using Promises to call the next loop cycle.

```js
function loop(max, callback, i) {
  i = i || 0;
  if (i < max) {
    console.log("loop count: " + i);
    return callback(i).then(function() {
      return loop(max, callback, ++i);
    });
  }
}

function doAsyncStuff(passedNum) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Fake asynchronous stuff for 500ms using setTimeout.
    // Put your real async code here, calling "resolve" when
    // it's finished.
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("callback count: " + passedNum);
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

loop(5, doAsyncStuff).then(function() {
  console.log('All done looping!')
});
```

Comment: You might want to put the "real async code" from the question in your answer

Comment: @Bergi Huh? The promise is returned, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work. Also, I'd rather have a working code snippet that teaches someone how to implement Promises than a non-working snippet that pastes in a block of code that is not relevant to the OP's original question, which was how to use Promises to make the loop's cycle work with an asynchronous callback.

Comment: Neither your `loop` function nor the `then` callback function inside it return promises, despite being asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi Sure. It's a little out of scope for the question, but fine idea. Updated and thanks!

Comment: @rgthree this is an amazing answer, achieves exactly what I want in a very elegant way. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using promise of javascript

```
 function callback(item) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('callback item ', item);
    resolve(item);
   });
 }

 function loopCall(num) {
   for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
         console.log('loop item ', i);
         callback(i).then(function(data) {

         }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Something Broke');
         })
   }
 }

loopCall(120);
```

This is the way you can get your desired output.If you want use node.js environment and there has a npm module [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/).

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is very helpful. I have accepted the answer above though as it is more comprehensive.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. It only works because the `console.log('callback item ', item);` in `callback` is synchronously invoked